# arduino on windows 8 stuck open but can't find in task manager

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, arduino

I deleted a folder from within the arduino 'open folder' function in their program, and the mouseover window got stuck on my screen.  So I tried taskkill /f /im dwm.exe and it worked to reset the windows manager, but it didn't remove the stuck window from the screen.  The arduino program logo is also in the taskbar, but it won't maximize when I click on it, and it won't go away when I right click ->close.  It's also not appearing anywhere in the task manager.  Can I get rid of it without restarting?

EDIT: I can't seem to find arduino in the task manager or in cmd->tasklist even when I open a new instance.  Anyone know what I should look for in the taskmanager?

Comment: Is it listed in process explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Renju, for the comment.  I used [process-explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out it was javaw.exe that had frozen.  As soon as I restared javaw.exe I was able to close the arduino IDE.

Comment: Latest version is always available [directly from Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Don't waste your time with these third-party sites.